# SSL Poke connection issue ( Jenkins to Sonarqube )

Tags: ssl, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am using Jenkins 1.643 and SonarQube 5.1

While trying to access SonarQube URL via SSLPoke from a Jenkins server (with jdk 1.6), I'm getting the below error

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java SSLPoke sonarqube-b.test.com 443
```

> java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:114)
>           at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:31)**

The same is working fine with jkd 1.7

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java SSLPoke sonarqube-b.test.com 443
```

> Successfully connected

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 is ancient so it likely doesn't meet the minimal security requirements on the server side (e.g. ciphers not secure enough).

If you want to figure out why Java is closing the connection on the server side, then add `sonar.web.javaOpts=-Djavax.net.debug=all` to your *sonar.properties*, restart your SonarQube server and (when using `SSLPoke`) inspect the SSL handshake in the server logs.